# Alternate Text Color in JTextPane

Tags: swing, types, colors, jtextpane, mismatch

I'm trying to alternate text color in a JTextPane without changing the color of the entire JTextPane.
I found a class online that allows you to do this, but when i tried to create a "ColorPane" object in order to run the method he provided, the code compiled but simply did not work. My laptop just played the typical "Windows no-no sound".
So I'm trying now just to add the method i need but i'm getting some type mismatch errors.

Here is the ColorPane class: (I just took out the methods that created the table)
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/ExtensionofJTextPanethatallowstheusertoeasilyappendcoloredtexttothedocument.htm

Here is the method with the type mismatch errors:
http://pastebin.com/jWtQK0Va

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your problem it seems like you wanted multiple colours inside your JTextPane.
You just need to put this method in your code and provide the arguments as needed.

```
    public void appendToPane(String yourText, Color colour)
    {
      StyleContext sc = StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext();
      AttributeSet aset = sc.addAttribute(SimpleAttributeSet.EMPTY, StyleConstants.Foreground, colour);
      aset = sc.addAttribute(aset, StyleConstants.FontFamily, "Lucida Console");

      int len = tPane.getDocument().getLength();
      tPane.setCaretPosition(len);
      tPane.setCharacterAttributes(aset, false);
      tPane.replaceSelection(yourText);
    }
```

The above method uses the following imports :

- import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
- import javax.swing.text.SimpleAttributeSet;
- import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
- import javax.swing.text.StyleContext;
- import javax.swing.JTextPane;

And tPane is the Object of JTextPane. Just simply like if you want Your Name to appear in blue colour, call method as appendToPane("Your Name", Color.BLUE); and now if you want your other text to appear red, then call the method again appendToPane("New Text", Color.RED);.Hoping this will solve the query you asked for.

Regards

Comment: Thanks! minor typo: STyleConstants should be StyleConstants